# SoapUI How to get Request and Response size for each TestStep

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a bit of Groovy script that loops through the test steps in the current test case and sums the response time for each step and stores it in a custom property on the test case.

I am now trying to do the same for each test step's request and response size but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
def TestCase = testRunner.getTestCase()
def CurrentTestStep = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(context.getCurrentStepIndex()).getLabel()
def StepList = TestCase.getTestStepList().name - CurrentTestStep

def ResponseTime = 0
def RequestSize = 0
def ResponseSize = 0

StepList.each
{ Step ->
    try
    {
        ResponseTime = ResponseTime + testRunner.testCase.testSteps[Step].testRequest.response.timeTaken
    }
    catch(Exception expObj)
    {

    } 
}

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Time", ResponseTime.toString())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can us below statement for the Response size.

```
 log.info "Size of " + Step  + "is " +  testRunner.testCase.testSteps[Step].testRequest.response.responseSize
```

the full code would be

```
def TestCase = testRunner.getTestCase()
def CurrentTestStep = 
context.testCase.getTestStepAt(context.getCurrentStepIndex()).getLabel()
def StepList = TestCase.getTestStepList().name - CurrentTestStep
def ResponseTime = 0
def RequestSize = 0
def ResponseSize = 0

  StepList.each
  {
  Step ->
  try
  {
     log.info "Size of " + Step  + "is " +  testRunner.testCase.testSteps[Step].testRequest.response.responseSize 

  ResponseSize=    ResponseSize + testRunner.testCase.testSteps[Step].testRequest.response.responseSize 

 }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  }
}

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Test_Case_Response_Size", ResponseSize.toString())
```

For request size i was not able to find the statement to get size. will Add once get it.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. The response size is much more important than the request. So i can move forward with this for now.